# Создать кнопку на disnake

Tags: python, discord, disnake

меня очень давно волнует вопрос как сделать кнопку на disnake, я слышал что это disnake.ui. Всё перечитал, не понял ничего. Буду благодарен.

Answer (score 3):

Хоть ответ и поступает в течение месяца, могу дать 3 варианта кнопок

1. кнопка с простым выводом текста в чат:

```
class Role_list(disnake.ui.View):
    def __init__ (self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.value: Optional[bool] = None

    @disnake.ui.button(label='Вывод текса',style=disnake.ButtonStyle.gray)
    async def vivod_texta(self,button:disnake.Button,interaction:disnake.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message('Проверка')
```

2. выдача роли по кнопке

```
   @disnake.ui.button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.grey,label='Черный',row=1)
    async def Black (self,button:disnake.Button,interaction:disnake.Interaction):
        Black = interaction.guild.get_role(1072561365438451743)
        if Black in interaction.user.roles:
            await interaction.user.remove_roles(Black)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f'{Black.mention} Успешно забрана',ephemeral=True)
            
        else: 
            await interaction.user.add_roles(Black)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f'{Black.mention} Успешно присвоено',ephemeral=True)
```

Если у вас возникает вопрос касаемо этого участка кода

```
if Black in interaction.user.roles:
            await interaction.user.remove_roles(Black)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f'{Black.mention} Успешно забрана',ephemeral=True)

        else: 
            await interaction.user.add_roles(Black)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f'{Black.mention} Успешно присвоено',ephemeral=True)
```

Объясню. Чтобы не делать много кнопок,а не дай бог кнопки для очистки всех ролей. Сделаем небольшую проверку на на наличие роли у пользователя

3. кнопки принятия и отказа

```
class Confirm(disnake.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=10.0)
        self.value: Optional[bool] = None

    
    @disnake.ui.button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.grey,emoji='✅')
    async def confirm(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, inter: disnake.MessageInteraction):
        self.value = True
        self.stop()
        
    
    @disnake.ui.button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.grey,emoji='❌')
    async def cancel(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, inter: disnake.MessageInteraction):
        self.value = False
        self.stop()
```

Итак, кнопки и их виды я дал,но не показал как применять
P.s для третьего вида потребуется импорт `from typing import Optional`
Внимательный читатель мог увидеть ,что в выдаче роли по кнопке использовалось:

```
await interaction.response.send_message(f'{Black.mention} Успешно забрана',ephemeral=True)
```

ephemeral означает видимое ли это сообщение или нет
interaction совмещает в себе класс disnake.Member
А также является чем-то вроде cxt. Прочесть подробнее о методах и атрибутах interaction можно [здесь](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/api.html#interaction)

Чтобы применять первые два варианта кнопка достаточно просто сделать следующий код:

```
@commands.command(name='verify')
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def verify(self,ctx):
        view=Verify_button()
        verify_embed = disnake.Embed(
            title='Верификация',
            description='Пройдите верификацию чтобы продолжить общение!'
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=verify_embed,view=view)
```

А чтобы использовать кнопки принятия потребуются условные операторы
код ниже :

```
    @commands.command(name='test')
    async def test(self,ctx):
        view = Confirm()
        message = await ctx.send ('Тест',view=view)
        await view.wait()
        if view is None:
            await ctx.send('Вы не успели)')
        elif view.value:
            message.delete()
            await ctx.send('тест успешно пройден')
        else:
            message.delete()
            await ctx.send('тест успешно провален')
```