# Python discord bot, disnake

Tags: python, discord, бот

Пожалуйста помогите как сделать кулдаун для кнопок??? У меня получилось сделать только кулдаун команды:

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 21600, commands.BucketType.user)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**В классе кнопки в функции `__init__` укажите значение timeout:**

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(timeout=20)
    self.value = Optional[bool]
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте класс, а затем укажите время секундах,
советую сделать так :

```
class Role_list(disnake.ui.View):
    def __init__ (self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.value: Optional[bool] = None
```

В `super().__init__(timeout=None)` в скобках есть timeout . timeout указывается в секундах. Если вы хотите чтобы времени не было,тогда пропишите None, в остальных случаях задаете определенное значение
Если хотите ознакомиться с различными типами кнопок и как их использовать, советую посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1482860/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-disnake/1499705#1499705)
Спасибо ,что прочли мой ответ.